# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. cant be solved

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import brute

class contrarian_strategy():
    def __init__(self,ticker):
        self.ticker=ticker
        self.get_data()
        #self.test_strategy()
    def get_data(self):
        data=yf.download(self.ticker)["Close"].to_frame()
        data["returns"]=np.log(data.Close.div(data.Close.shift(1)))
        self.data=data
        return data
    def test_strategy(self,window):
        self.window=window
        self.data["positions"]= -np.sign(self.data["returns"].rolling(int(window)).mean())
        self.data["strategy"]= self.data["positions"]*self.data["returns"]
        self.data["creturns"]=self.data["returns"].cumsum().apply(np.exp)
        self.data["cstrategy"]=self.data["strategy"].cumsum().apply(np.exp)
        self.results=self.data
        #absolute strategy performance
        perf_strat=self.data["cstrategy"].iloc[-1]
        #buy and hold absolute performance
        perf_buy_and_hold=self.data["creturns"].iloc[-1]
        return perf_strat,perf_buy_and_hold
    def plot_returns(self):
        title="{}".format(self.ticker)
        
        return self.results.plot(figsize=(15,15),title=title)
        
        plt.show()
    def optimize_results(self,windowrange):#,windowrangehigh,step):
        opt=brute(self.test_strategy,[windowrange])#,windowrangehigh,step))
        return opt
```

should i use scipy minimize instead of brute as i want to optimize window parameter only???:-if yes can you show to do that please?
please do help me if you know it
when i run this code by tsla.optimize_results((10,50,1))method i get :-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-31e36e1901a4> in <module>
----> 1 aapl.optimize_results((10,50,1))

<ipython-input-97-b3ff81b5303c> in optimize_results(self, windowrange)
     34         plt.show()
     35     def optimize_results(self,windowrange):#,windowrangehigh,step):
---> 36         opt=brute(self.test_strategy,[windowrange])#,windowrangehigh,step))
     37         return opt

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py in brute(func, ranges, args, Ns, full_output, finish, disp, workers)
   3266 
   3267         # run minimizer
-> 3268         res = finish(func, xmin, args=args, **finish_kwargs)
   3269 
   3270         if isinstance(res, OptimizeResult):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py in fmin(func, x0, args, xtol, ftol, maxiter, maxfun, full_output, disp, retall, callback, initial_simplex)
    541             'initial_simplex': initial_simplex}
    542 
--> 543     res = _minimize_neldermead(func, x0, args, callback=callback, **opts)
    544     if full_output:
    545         retlist = res['x'], res['fun'], res['nit'], res['nfev'], res['status']

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py in _minimize_neldermead(func, x0, args, callback, maxiter, maxfev, disp, return_all, initial_simplex, xatol, fatol, adaptive, **unknown_options)
    687 
    688     for k in range(N + 1):
--> 689         fsim[k] = func(sim[k])
    690 
    691     ind = np.argsort(fsim)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

should i use scipy minimize instead of brute as i want to optimize window parameter only???:-if yes can you show to do that please?
please do help me if you know it

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `brute` or even looked at its docs, but I suspect problem is with the  return of your func

```
self.test_strategy
...
return perf_strat,perf_buy_and_hold
```

That's a tuple.  What does `brute` require?  Looks like it expects a single float.

```
fsim[k] = func(sim[k])
```

Before randomly trying other optimizing functions, make sure you understand what the function requires.  That means reading, and necessary rereading, the docs.  Make sure you understand the examples (if any).  You can't cheat - the optimizer will call your function in a very specific way, and expect an specific type of return - such as a scalar, or may be an array that matches the input in shape.